# How to find the location of currently working XCode Project,if there are many with same name in Mac?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on an XCode Project, there are many projects with same names in my Mac.
how do find the exact location of current project ?

On right click->show in finder leads me to biuld phases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple

> Right click on your project->Show in Finder

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for ur answe prateek...but i got problem on that thats why i posted the question here
On right click->show in finder leads biuld phases 

Any way i will include this also in my question

Comment: can you attach some screenshot of it

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the .xcodeproj in top tool bar of your Xcode project. It will show the folder hierarchy of your project. Hope this helps...